# webm file not playing on safari and firefox on mac, nor on the iphone

Tags: html, video, webm

I embedded a webm video file in the html of the website http://www.dolcini.berlin
It only runs in google chrome on mac, it doesn't in safari, in firefox, and any browser on the iphone.
The code is:
`<video width="100%" src="../img/dolcini_movie.webm" autplay controls></video>`
I tried it with mp4 as well, but that didn't work neither. I converted the mp4 file to webm online.

Comment: Why do you need to use webM exactly? Safari prefers MP4 and MOV... PS: Google owns `.webm`, so it works on their browser. Apple owns `.mov` and is also an MPEG licensor (eg: `.mp4` files), so one of those two formats should work on Safari.